# Can I get information about the Symfony2 response object from js file

Tags: javascript, symfony

I'm using Symfony2.
I want to do some validation in a php controller in that way:

```
if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $old_name = $category->getName();

            $new_name = $request->get('value');

            if ($same == 0) {  
                //valid
                $new_response = new Response($name);
                return $new_response; 
            } else { 
                //not valid
                $old_response = new Response($old_name);
                return $old_response;
            }  
 }
```

Is there a way to check in the .js file which response was sent - `$new_response` or `$old_response`? The point in this is to append to the body a message saying to the user that he entered a duplicate value if the response sent was `$old_response`. And to remove this message if the response sent was `$new_response`.

Thank you very much in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use **[JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)** for returning a set of data, not only the name.

**Controller:**

```
    if ($same == 0) {  
        //valid
        $new_response = new JsonResponse(array('type' => 'new', 'name' => $name));
        return $new_response; 
    } else { 
        //not valid
        $old_response = new JsonResponse(array('type' => 'old', 'name' => $old_name));
        return $old_response;
    }
```

**JS:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '...',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 'value=...',
    success: function(json) {
        if (json.type == 'new')
            // this is new response
        else
            // this is old or some other response

        alert(json.name); // this is the response body (old or new name)
    }
});
```

See also:

- [Creating a JSON response](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#creating-a-json-response)
- [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

Simply look in the response body. The first constructer parameter is the content (normally a parsed template) of the response.

Maybe you want to use a `JsonResponse($data)`